# How can I create a tiled image in code that is also data-bound?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Current in code-behind, I dynamically create a WPF Image control and bind the source to a custom databinding.  This will eventually be added to a grid to provide a background image:

```
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
myImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, myBinding);
```

The problem is that I want to tile this image, so the only way I can find to do this is to create an ImageBrush and set the TileMode property.  But there is no "SetBinding" function, so how can I accomplish what I need?

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
myBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
// Can't do this!
myBrush.SetBinding(ImageBrush.SourceImageProperty, myBinding);
```

Are there any other ways to tile an image like this in code-behind?

Comment: What grid did you mean -"grid layout" or "data grid"?

Comment: A standard grid layout. Currently, I place the Image control into the grid, but I would ideally like to create an ImageBrush and set the grid background to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not to change anything but use the BindingOperations:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myBrush, ImageBrush.ImageSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

And you need to define the Viewport and the fill the viewport with brush:

```
MyBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0.1, 0.1);
// Create a rectangle and paint it with the ImageBrush.
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
rec.Stroke = Brushes.LimeGreen;
rec.StrokeThickness = 1;
rec.Fill = MyBrush;
```

Comment: Thanks, this most directly answers my question. BindingOperations.SetBinding() was the key here. Instead of using a Rectangle, I just set the background of my Grid to be that ImageBrush.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following. In debugmode the property of the VisualBrush is set correctly. Certainly the image is show as a stretched image. Don't know why. Hope it helps.

the property

```
        public TileMode Mode { get; set; }
```

the binding

```
        VisualBrush myBrush = new VisualBrush();

        Uri uri = new Uri("picture.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        ImageSource src = new BitmapImage(uri);
        myBrush.Visual = new Image() { Source = src };

        this.Mode = TileMode.Tile;

        Binding bind = new Binding() { Source = Mode };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(myBrush, VisualBrush.TileModeProperty, bind);

        this.Background = myBrush;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like code behind, so it's hard to me to write code-behind sample quickly.
Here's markup sample:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Sample.jpg" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,0.5,0.5"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Instead of hard-coded image (`ImageSource="Sample.jpg"`) you can write any binding expression like this: `ImageSource="{Binding MyBackgroundImageUri}"`.